# Advice on best way to structure database tables

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following tables to create in a database.

1. Customer Registration
2. Customer
3. Scheme

Customer Registration has the following columns:

- CustomerRegistrationId
- CustomerId
- SchemeId

Customer has the following columns:

- CustomerId
- CustomerName
- CustomerAddress

Scheme has the following columns:

- SchemeId
- SchemeName
- IsActive

A Customer Registration can have only one Customer.
A Customer Registration can have many Schemes.

So my question is to whether is it better to structure the database tables like I have above.  So if a Customer Registration had multiple Schemes the data would look something like....

**Customer:**

12,    John Smith,    1234 Park Road

**Scheme:**

1,    Multiple Buy Savings,    True

2,    School Book Scheme,    True

3,   Student Discount,    True

**Customer Registration:**

1,   12,    2

2, 12, 3

So Customer Registration has multiple entries for the same Customer for each Scheme.

Or would it be better to implement a table that only stored the Customer Registration and Scheme Id.  E.g.

**CustomerRegistraion_Scheme_Link**

- CustomerRegistrationId
- SchemeId

And Change **Customer Registration** to:

- CustomerRegistrationId
- CustomerId

So the data above would now look like:

**Customer:**

12,    John Smith,    1234 Park Road

**Scheme:**

1,    Multiple Buy Savings,    True

2,    School Book Scheme,    True

3,   Student Discount,    True

**Customer Registration:**

1,   12

**CustomerRegistration_Scheme_Link:**

1, 2

1, 3

I'd appreciate any advice, thanks :)

Comment: "Would it be better" means nothing unless you define "better". If you want to know what "better" means then it is time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design.

Comment: Oh gawd! Really?! I guess I assumed it would be obvious that "better" meant which is the best way to structure the database tables as the heading is "Advice on best way to structure database tables".

Comment: Hi. So apparently in other words you don't mean anything by it, you are just using the word to refer to whatever other people mean by it, and that is too broad a question & the balancing of a textbook full of relevant aspects including ones particular to your situation that you didn't give and don't know to give. Hence, time to read a textbook. "I'd appreciate any advice, " is not an on-topic question. See [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461